# Purpose of tracking non-remote branch

Tags: git

Usually, a local branch tracks a remote branch. The remote branch will be updated when pushing or pulling.

But what is the purpose of letting a local branch track another local branch?

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen that done - it might be possible, though, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with Git and you have multiple features you are working on simultaneously, it is good practice to have a separate branch for each feature. When a feature is completed, you push it into the main branch.

The other branches should then pull from the main branch to make sure that their changes are compatible with the completed branch so that potential merge problems are detected early.

In that case it would be convenient when all feature branches would track the local main branch.

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought of this. Do you use this workflow personally?

Comment: I usually try to avoid working on more than one problem at the same time. But in those cases where it is unavoidable, like when an urgent fix is needed, I usually create a new branch based on the released version. This allows to separate the fix from my current work.

Comment: Phillip, does your feature branch tracks the main local branch or the main remote branch? If the local branch: do I understand it correctly, that in this case pushing is a completely local operation? Is pulling similar?

Comment: When it's a collaborative project with a remote central repository, I would track the remote branch. When it's a private project I would have everything on my machine, so the main branch I track would be a local one. The nice thing about Git is that you can use it completely local without the need of an external server.